# Powershell - .GetType().InvokeMember() throws Type mismatch Error

Tags: sql, powershell, windows-installer

I am trying to extract certain values from an .msi file with Powershell to help automate an installation. I came across a method involving calling InvokeMember() such as [example 1](http://www.adamtheautomator.com/powershell-windows-installer-msi-properties/) and [example 2](http://www.scconfigmgr.com/2014/08/22/how-to-get-msi-file-information-with-powershell/).

I tried this myself with the following code -

```
$windowsInstaller = New-Object -ComObject WindowsInstaller.Installer
$mSIPath =  $prereqComponent.getAttribute("msiFilename")
$mSIDatabase = $windowsInstaller.GetType().InvokeMember(
    "OpenDatabase", 
    "InvokeMethod", 
    $null, 
    $windowsInstaller, 
    @($mSIPath.FullName, 0) 
)
```

Whenever I run the above in Powershell v2.0 in Windows 7 SP1 I get the following error -

> Exception calling "InvokeMember" with "5" argument(s): "Type mismatch.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))" At line:3 char:56
>
> - $mSIDatabase = $windowsInstaller.GetType().InvokeMember <<<< ("OpenDatabase", "InvokeMethod", $null, $windowsInstaller, @($mSIPath,
>     0))
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodTargetInvocation

Looking up the [error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.vsconstants.disp_e_typemismatch.aspx) I first thought that maybe it was down to `msiFilename` but calling `Test-Path $mSIPath` gives `True` and it is definitely a working .msi file as I have installed it previously.

After trying to tweak the arguments I am at a loss. Could anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I'm a little thrown off by the use of `$mSIPath`.  I believe your object should be that `mSIPath` should be of type `IO.FileInfo` - is that accurate?  (__NOTE__: I ask this because `$prereqComponent` isn't defined in the above snippet, but I assume that's what it is intended as)

Comment: That's absolutely right. The code above had been tweaked from what I originally had the error with. I realised that the reason I got the error in the first place was that for some reason the full path was being resolved incorrectly so Powershell never found my file. since playing around with it I passed a string path instead of System.IO.Path object. If you submit it as an answer I will accept it. Both probelms lead to the same error message so I didn't notice my second mistake.

Comment: Glad to hear - by the way, great question write-up, lots of good detail there, and excellently formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code snippet provided, it looks like your `$msiPath` should be of type `IO.FileInfo`.

Since we cannot see the `$prereqComponent` object classification, it may be useful to assign the fully qualified path name (FQPN, such as: `C:\Users\Me\Desktop\File`), or ensure the `$msiPath` above is of type `IO.FileInfo`.